# Convert timestamp to wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I am using this code to detect timestamp from content.

```
  $pattern = '/(<div\s+[^<]*?\bclass="[^<"]*\btimestamp\b[^<]*?>[^<]*)?(?<!:)\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?(?!(?::\d{2})?\s*[ap]\.?m\.?)(?!.*?["\'])/';
  $foundTimestamp = preg_replace_callback($pattern, array($this, 'spp_ts_callback'), $content);

  function spp_ts_callback($m) {
      return empty($m[1]) ? '[spp-timestamp time="'. $m[0] . '"]' : $m[0];
  }
```

it works on plan content for example

```
$content= '05:10  Hani shares some time-saving podcast automation tips';
```

But if i just put a link next to it it not works

```
$content='05:10  Hani shares some time-saving podcast automation tips <a href="http://wordpress.org">http://wordpress.org</a>';
```

Comment: but you haven't put the div from which you fetch your content... but in your regex you have div ???

Comment: Yes i have div its mean it will not detect timestamp which div have class "timestamp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original Regex:

```
/(<div\s+[^<]*?\bclass="[^<"]*\btimestamp\b[^<]*?>[^<]*)?(?<!:)\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?(?!(?::\d{2})?\s*[ap]\.?m\.?)(?!.*?["\'])/
```

at the end, you have put a negative look ahead (?!.*?["\']) which matches **"** marks... and your 2nd content has

> "http://w which contains

quotation marks... that is why it is not captured.

Just removed the " mark from your regex:

```
(<div\s+[^<]*?\bclass="[^<"]*\btimestamp\b[^<]*?>[^<]*)?(?<!:)\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?(?!(?::\d{2})?\s*[ap]\.?m\.?)(?!.*?[\'])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KTmv7Z/2/)